# Как отправить POST запрос через HTTPS?

Tags: node.js

делаю так:

```
var postData = querystring.stringify({
    'msg' : 'Hello World!'
});

var options = {
    hostname: 'myserver',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'POST',

    rejectUnauthorized: false,

    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
    }
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(ch) {
        console.log('BODY:', ch);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log('END');
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('error:',e);
});

req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

в ответ приходит ошибка:

> { [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 647, code: 'HPE_INVALID_CONSTANT' }

в гугле решения не нашел

может кто просветит, изза чего возникла ошибка?

Comment: а что это кавычки странные какие-то?

Comment: @olegkalenchuk, изза копи-паста. поправил